# How can I set the working directory to a subfolder?

Tags: r, directory, purrr

I am using R to try to read all the .xlsx files in a subfolder within a main folder. The code seems intuitive, but I am stumbling into a roadblock with the working directory.

My relevant code:

```
setwd("~/Downloads/Job Postings")

for (dir in list.dirs()[-1]) {
  setwd(dir)

  files <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")

  require(purrr)
  main_dF <- files %>% map_dfr(read.xlsx)
}
```

The code seems intuitive, but I receive error `Error in setwd(dir) : cannot change working directory`. How can I adjust the `setwd()` command? Thanks

Comment: Please check the `dir` by `print(dir)` or  `list.dirs()[-1]`

Comment: I had checked the ```dir``` earlier and it seemed right --- ```print(dir)``` returns the first subfolder within my main folder. However, ```list.dirs()[-1]``` returns ```character(0)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two issues.

1. You change directory into a sub directory in the loop, but never return
2. You assign the result to `main_df`, but that won't ever be accumulated across the subdirectories

You might try something list this.

```
setwd("~/Downloads/Job Postings")
results <- list()
for (dir in list.dirs()[-1]) {
  setwd(dir)

  files <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")
  require(purrr)
  main_dF <- files %>% map_dfr(read.xlsx)
  results[[dir]] <- main_df
  setwd("~/Downloads/Job Postings")
}
finalresult <- bind_rows(results)
```

Comment: Really neat reply. Thanks for the extra help on accumulating the file across the loop, hadn't even gotten to thinking about that! I will add that although the  ```results[[dir]] <- main_df``` code makes sense to me, I'm receiving ```Error: object 'results' not found```

Comment: Make sure you include the vital second line of the answer outside the loop, `results <- list()`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Thanks for walking me through that